Override instanceof in Java for extended classes
I have extended a class like this:
public class JDateTextField extends JTextField {...}

Calling instanceof  JTextField on a new JDateTextField will return 'true', since it was extended from that class.
I am wondering if there is a work around so 'false' is returned instead. The following solution gets ugly very soon, especially when the number of extended classes increases:
JDateTextField dateTextField = new JDateTextField; 
if (dateTextField  instanceof JTextField 
    && !(dateTextField  instanceof JDateTextField)) {...} // returns false and skips the 'if', which is the intended behavior   

Is there a simple solution to effectively override the instanceof return type of an extended class? With the result that the following would also return false:
JDateTextField dateTextField = new JDateTextField; 
if (dateTextField  instanceof JTextField {...} 


You cannot override instanceof. But you can use getClass() == JDateTextField.

This sounds like the XY problem: what are you trying to use this for?

It doesn't make sense to override instanceof, as instanceof is an operator, not a method. And its "return type" is boolean.

You haven't made it clear what the problem is. Why does the behavior of instanceof create a problem for you?

Im iterating over dozens of GUI elements. Most of them are JTextField, some are JDateTextField, and some other types. They are unordered. So by doing  "instanceof JTextField" I also catch JDateTextField, which is wrong behavior for what Im trying to do.

The order of the GUI elements isn't in your control, but the order you check instanceof is: check if it is a JDateTextField first and do something, if not, check if it's a JTextField and do something for that - in the second case, it's guaranteed not to be a JDateTextField, because that would have been handled earlier. With that said, you've not actually described what you want to do once you identify the type: instanceof checks can often be replaced with better approaches; we can't suggest one without knowing what you need.

"Im iterating over dozens of GUI elements" -- why do you need to do this? I'm with @AndyTurner in that this still sounds like an XY Problem where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. It would probably be better if you could tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Suggestion by @AndyTurner does the job. I added a basic example of what Im doing.

As suggested by @AndyTurner, reordering of if-checks. Basic example:
public class JTextFieldNew extends JTextField {

    public JTextFieldNew(String placeholder, int columns) {
        super(placeholder, columns);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                panel.add(new JTextField());
            } else {
                panel.add(new JTextFieldNew("", 1));
            }
        }
        Component[] components = panel.getComponents();

        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JTextFieldNew) {
                System.out.println("JTextFieldNew");
                // handle JTextFieldNew
            } else if (component instanceof JTextField) {
                System.out.println("JTextField");
                // handle JTextField
            }
        }
    }
}


Perfect case for pattern matching, especially when you have to test for more types.
